# Does the Facebook C# SDK have any OAuth 2.0 authentication baked into the library?

Tags: oauth, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm wanting to create a website and have users log in to my site, etc. BUT I don't want to have to get them to create a username/password, etc. So I'll ask them to authenticate with their Facebook account (assuming they have one).

So I've had a look at the [Authentication docs on Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and I'm wondering if

- Does the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) have any libraries/code that does a lot of this heavy lifting?
- If so, any links to sample code I can see? I've tried having a look at the Samples folder in the source code .. but there's nothing that suggests this.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one example using [MVC3 and the Facebook C# SDK library](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Website%20%28With%20Javascript%20SDK%29&referringTitle=Getting%20Started)

Comment: Yup, this is very close to what I do on my site, http://www.atmybase.com. The Facebook C# SDK is very easy to use. I highly recommend using it rather than trying to build your own Facebook code.

Comment: I have used Facebook C# SDK to get the access token which can't be used further for the request like the like, name etc
as the access token which is returned is less then 118 character
I am creating C# console application.